# DLL dependency in different system or OS

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll, emgucv

**Development Environment**

```
Development OS : Windows 8.1 Pro
VS : 2013
App: Winform & WPF
MSSQL : 2012
EF : 6.0
EMGU.CV : 3.0.0
ffmpeg, Nreco, office.interop and several other plugins installed with app.
```

We have developed a vehicle tracking system with the help of emgu.cv for image processing. we are using capture method to grab images from the input video file and process images. Any way, the application is almost done. To test the application, we are trying it in several machines. Like with different cores / different OS (w7/w8/w8.1/w10) etc.

we are installing MSSQL express 2012, .net fw 4.5, 4.5.1, before using the app in pc's where vs is not installed.

in most of the case, our test pc has VS 2013, and in those pc, there are no problem running this application.

Some pc have adobe products but not VS. But they are running the application too.

But those pc, just have installed or dont have any adobe product or VS, they are crashing at the same point( in 5 pc).

```
    Application: VehicleTrackingSystem.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvReleaseCapture(IntPtr ByRef)
   at Emgu.CV.Capture.DisposeObject()
   at Emgu.Util.DisposableObject.Dispose(Boolean)
   at Emgu.Util.DisposableObject.Finalize()
```

Same solution is running in several pc as mentioned before. But in some cases, it shows (basically in win 7) `System.dllnotfoundexception`.

Its assumed that, some dlls are mismatching, may be because of VS installation or adobe product installation. I have tried **Dependency Walker** but in Positive PC and negetive PC all dll is similar. But the dll's file version is not same though.

how to solve this?

Comment: How about shipping all your dlls with solution? Check the references every project in solution uses and make sure they're not somewhere on C:/Program Files/. Instead copy them to project directory and set the flag to always copy.

Comment: Yes, all dll of my solution is copied perfectly. The dll mimatch may be occuring in system's dll. because there are a lots of dependency in systems dll

Comment: You have a *lot* of dependencies, forgetting to copy a DLL that can accidentally be present on a happy machine is a very easy mistake.  Dependency Walker isn't nearly good enough to diagnose such mishaps, use SysInternals' Process Monitor instead.  The trace shows your program searching for a DLL and not finding it.

Comment: @HansPassant my last testing result is, I was trying in a system and it was not running and showing same error.

At that point I just started installing VS2013, and after completion of VC++, ARM libraries, I have start my process and its working now!!

Comment: Well, sure, installing VS adds a *lot* of DLLs.  Forgetting to copy the C runtime library (msvcrxxx.dll) is a standard oversight.